# How to display multiple months in CLNDR.js

Tags: jquery, html, date

Instead of the traditional one month view with CLNDR.js, I'd like to display two months, however I cannot find any documentation that shows how this is possible.

http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Update. Multi-month views are now supported out of the box via the `lengthOfTime` setting. An example configuration might look like this:

```
$('#cldnr-container').clndr({
    lengthOfTime: {
        months: 3,
        interval: 3
    }
});
```

This would render a three month view, where paging (clicking "next" or "previous") would move the calendar 3 months at a time.

Comment: This does not work with versions 1.4.6 and 1.4.7. It causes an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined**.

Comment: @Fernando I double-checked and this works for me with v1.4.7. The setting is referenced in the project readme [here](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/blob/master/README.md) (search for "lengthOfTime").

Comment: Hi @chukkwagon, sorry for taking so long to answer. Yes, it works. My problem was with the template I used, which was the default one. In order to use multi-mont views you must use a different template, which is not documented (I guess) but is in the demo page (id="template-calendar-months"). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making 3 instances, like:

```
var $multipleCalendar = {
    left: $('#calendarLeft').clndr(...),
    middle: $('#calendarMiddle').clndr(...),
    right: $('#calendarRight').clndr(...)
};
```

You have to change some CSS to make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9049o5xp/5/) look better, but i think this is a [start](http://jsfiddle.net/9049o5xp/5/):

Have fun